# Issue with click event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use an image as a file type button in my application, but on click of image the function is executing but button  `document.getElementById("myFile").click();` is not executing. Whats wrong with my code?

HTML:

```
  <div align="center">
      <a href="#" id="other-color" onClick='loadFile()'><img style="width:75px;height:auto" src="icons/slr-camera-2-256.png"/></a>
      <input type="file" id="myFile" style="display:none" />
    </div>
```

Script:

```
 function loadFile()
        {

            alert("test");
            document.getElementById("myFile").click();
        }
```

Comment: removed both `html5` and `jQuery` tags, as this question doesn't have either

Comment: Your code works fine for me! It should be smthing else

Comment: @Precious If using jQuery is acceptable, please add the tag back. You can try selecting the element with jQuery like: `$('#myFile').click()`

Comment: it works fine for me.... but you should try with jquey

Comment: @RenePot `jQuery` tag could also mean that `jQuery` answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution by ([SpYk3HH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900807/spyk3hh)) [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/8fTfY/)  Or You can use the following:

```
$('#myFile').show();
$('#myFile').focus();
$('#myFile').click();
$('#myFile').hide();
```

The idea  of [Florin Mogos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871442/florin-mogos) is to make them visible and focused before click event.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, using JQuery:

```
 <input type="file" id="FileInput" style="display: none"/>
 <img src="abc.png" id="UploadPic" style="cursor: pointer;" />
```

And JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#FileInput").change(function() {
      $("#UploadPic").click();
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stay on the safe side, separate your JS from your HTML. You're not the first to have problems with JS events imbedded in HTML. I find that this issue is best solved when both are separated.

Here is a version when they are seperate.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/T3aBL/)

HTML

```
<div align="center"> <a href="#" id="other-color"><img style="width:75px;height:auto" src="icons/slr-camera-2-256.png"/></a>

    <input type="file" id="myFile" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var a = document.getElementById('other-color');
a.onclick = loadFile;

function loadFile() {
    alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use trigger**

**HTML**

```
<div align="center">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="other-color"><img style="width:75px;height:auto" src="icons/slr-camera-2-256.png"/></a>
   <input type="file" id="myFile" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#other-color').click(function(){
        $('#myFile').trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
```